# MPMoviePlayerViewController problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I play a movie in my app? I tried using this code, but xcode gives me this error:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"welcome" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
movieView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
theMovie = [movieView moviePlayer];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
theMovie.fullscreen = TRUE;
theMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
theMovie.shouldAutoplay = TRUE;

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview: movieView.view];
```

ERROR

```
ld: warning: in /Users/Rushil/Documents/StickDeath/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-MPMoviePlayerViewController in StickDeathViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that MPMoviePlayerViewController only available on iOS3.2 and later

Double check for that, I think that is the issue. [More here about MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/reference/reference.html)

Comment: I know it is only for ios 3.2 and later, but I have set my deployment target to 4.0, so that it my app will only run on 4.0 devices(just to test this) and it still doesn't work

Comment: To make this work do you have to manually add another view controller or something?

Comment: I think you set it wrongly. It is a build/compile error, not a runtime error so you don't need to add another viewcontroller. Xcode just doesn't find the class

Comment: set it wrongly? But what could I have set wrong? I checked the deployment target, and remimported the mediaplayer framework. Neither of which solved my issue

Comment: It looks like you were right, I started a new project, and it didn't throw the error. However, know it shows this:
Method definition for my ibaction not found
Code:
-(IBAction)m:(id)sender;
and then in my .m
-(IBAction)m{
code
}
and it still shows the error even after i comment out all the code inside the ibaction!

Comment: in your .m file, you forgot the argument m:(id)sender

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I was so stupid! I knew it was something small like that!!